# How a css selector is applied when reffering to multiple classes, ids, or elements?

Tags: css

Will this css:

```
.address, div {
    color:red;
}
```

Be applied on 1 or 2?

```
   1 <div id = "address"> 221B Baker Street </div>
   2 <span class="address"> 221B Baker Street </span>
```

Which one is correct and for which reason.

Comment: It will apply to both as you have put {,} in your CSS selection. That means OR condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will be matched. The comma (`,`) in CSS means "Or", so basically it will match `.address` OR `div`, translated to "any element with class of "address" (matches 2) OR any div (matches 1).

Answer (score 2):

The rule which you have written

```
.address, div {
    color:red;
 }
```

implies that the given style will be applied to elements those are having `address` class as well as all the `div` elements.

So If we consider your markup rule will be apply to both the elemnts

```
<div id ="address"> 221B Baker Street </div>  <!--div element -->
<span class="address"> 221B Baker Street </span> <!-- address class -->
```